# print the query - graphql printer

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, graphql, apollo

Is there any way I can see an exact query that runs in my app and print it on the log?

For example, I am running this query:

```
const handleSubmit = React.useCallback(() => {
    loadUsers({
      variables: {
        where: { firstName: (name.split(" "))[0], AND: [{lastName:(name.split(" "))[0]}]},
      },
    });
    console.log(print(loadUsers));
  }, [loadUsers, name]);
```

and I want to print and see what are the exact `firstName` and ```lastName`` parameters being passed into it. I read about this:

```
import { print } from 'graphql/language/printer';
```

and tried to use it like this:

```
console.log(print(loadUsers));
```

at the end of my `handleSubmit` but when I click on the button to run the query, I get an error saying that

`Invalid AST Node`.

How can I print and check my exact query? Could be any other way too - doesn't have to be with graphql printer necessarily.

Comment: inspect network requests!!

Comment: I'm unable to see network requests while using Xcode iOS simulator on Safari's JS Context developer tools. @xadm

Comment: create/use a proxy? hint: `{ firstName:name.split(" ")[0], , AND: [{ lastName:name.split(" ")[1] ...` and you could use normal `const lastName=name.split(" ")[1]; console.log( lastName);`

Comment: ... you can use links to log queries/requests ... f.e. `apollo-link-log`